# Count of non-nested documents per index

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there a way to count how many non-nested documents do multiple index have without them been combined into single result (so that I get result per index)?

I've tried:

- Index stats API - it returns both nested and non-nested summary in `"docs"` section (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-stats.html)
- `_cat` API - it returns combined count for all requested indexes (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat-count.html)
- `count API` - it returns combined count for all requested indexes (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-count.html)

Comment: Do you know all the names of nested fields that could appears on your indices?

Comment: @Lupanoide no, I don't know them in the service which is requesting this info (I could load them from metadata service but that would put a lot of load to my stats service and I'd like to avoid that). Also to note that I'd like to avoid search by any kind of nested field since it's a slow query and nested fields values are not mandatory (so searching or running aggregation queries is not the solution I'd like to have)

Comment: Thank you :) Exists query would do full-index scan and it also pre-requires that field value exists on each nested document (which I can't guarantee)